# How to register font in Java?

Tags: java, fonts, truetype

How can I register font in Java without using the class **GraphicsEnvironment**?

Unable to register font as the `rt` file I am using does not have the method `registerFont`.

Comment: what type of GUI library do you use? awt? swing? javaFx? other?

Comment: Not using any GUI. just a plain java code to convert pdf to image (jpeg)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). The code should include at least up to & including loading the `Font`. BTW - I'm not clear on what a 'rt file' is. Please explain that in an [edit] to the question.

Comment: so, what type of converter do you use?

Comment: i am using Pdfbox ..

Comment: rt.jar is the runtime jar in java which has the bootstrap classes

Comment: What type of JRE is this code being run in? The Sun/Oracle JRE & all compatible JREs has had the method since 1.6 (released almost 12 years ago).

Comment: we are using Java 8 but the rt jar is of 1.5 version

Comment: Tip: Add @jhamon (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"but the rt jar is of 1.5 version"* Bummer! Why is the client using such an old version (for which even **extended support** was dropped over 3 years ago)? I should point out: I have no idea how to implement the functionality required, sans upgrading clients to a 1.6+ JRE.